# Azure Resource Manager - Compare Two Parameters for Equality

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to perform custom validation on two `parameters` and ensure they are equal?
I want to have something like `password` and `password_confirm` that must be equal before deploying any of the resources.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you can hack something like that, just create a resource that will fail and all the other resources would depend on it and then on the resource condition do:

```
"condition": "[not(equals(parameters('password'), parameters('password_confirm'))]"
```

that way if they are not equal fake resource would start getting deployed and would blow up (make sure you code it to blow up) and nothing would get deployed

now that I think of it, instead of creating a resource, just put a condition on all of the resources in the template:

```
"condition": "[equals(parameters('password'), parameters('password_confirm')]"
```

that way they will only get deployed if these match, but you won't have a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add a parameter to do the validation... this is simpler but not as robust because the user could override the defaultValue of the parameter:

```
    "validatePasswords": {
      "type": "bool",
      "allowedValues": [
        true
      ],
      "defaultValue": "[equals(parameters('password'), parameters('password_confirm'))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Check to see if the 2 passwords match."
      }
    },
```

Putting a condition on each resource will work (and is harder to fool), but the deployment may succeed even though nothing is deployed.

Comment: This one seems a little less hacky than the other answer. I will probably try this out once this project is no longer on hold.